# bash Match contents of 2 files and append string to matching lines

Tags: awk, sed

I am working on Mac OS and I am new to shell.
I am having 2 files one **Main.txt** its contents are :

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'Sample' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Sample
  pod 'FirebaseCore', '7.8.0'
  pod 'GoogleUtilities', '7.2.2'
  pod 'FirebaseMessaging', '7.8.0'
  pod 'FirebaseCrashlytics', '7.8.0'
  pod 'FirebaseAnalytics', '7.8.0'
  pod 'FirebasePerformance', '7.8.0'
  pod 'Fluper', '2.0.0.1'
  pod 'lottie-ios', '2.5.0
  pod 'XYZ', :git => 'git@bitbucket.org:myteam/xyz.git', :commit => 'a32d154'
  pod 'ABC', :git => 'git@bitbucket.org:mytmteam/abc.git', :branch => 'debug101'
  pod 'myProject-auth-test', '2.0.0'
  pod 'myProject-network-test', '2.0.1'
  pod 'myProject-core-test', '2.0.1'
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '11.0'
          if config.name.include?("Release") || config.name.include?("Adhoc")
        config.build_settings['LLVM_LTO'] = 'YES_THIN'
      elsif config.name.include?("Debug")
        config.build_settings['LLVM_LTO'] = 'NO'
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And the other is **Module.txt** contents of which are:

```
  pod 'FirebaseCore'
  pod 'GoogleUtilities'
  pod 'FirebaseMessaging'
  pod 'FirebaseCrashlytics'
  pod 'FirebaseAnalytics'
  pod 'FirebasePerformance'
  pod 'Fluper'
  pod 'lottie-ios'
  pod 'myProject-auth-test'
  pod 'myProject-network-test'
  pod 'myProject-core-test'
```

I want to append

```
, :binary => true
```

at the end of all the matching lines In Main.txt from Module.txt,
So expected output should be (contents of Main.txt):

```
  pod 'FirebaseCore', '7.8.0', :binary => true
  pod 'GoogleUtilities', '7.2.2', :binary => true
  pod 'FirebaseMessaging', '7.8.0', :binary => true
  pod 'FirebaseCrashlytics', '7.8.0', :binary => true
  pod 'FirebaseAnalytics', '7.8.0', :binary => true
  pod 'FirebasePerformance', '7.8.0', :binary => true
  pod 'Fluper', '2.0.0.1', :binary => true
  pod 'lottie-ios', '2.5.0, :binary => true
  pod 'XYZ', :git => 'git@bitbucket.org:myteam/xyz.git', :commit => 'a32d154' 
  pod 'ABC', :git => 'git@bitbucket.org:mytmteam/abc.git', :branch => 'debug101'
  pod 'myProject-auth-test', '2.0.0', :binary => true
  pod 'myProject-network-test', '2.0.1', :binary => true
  pod 'myProject-core-test', '2.0.1', :binary => true
```

The following entries are ignored since they are not in Module.txt files

```
pod 'XYZ', :git => 'git@bitbucket.org:myteam/xyz.git', :commit => 'a32d154'
pod 'ABC', :git => 'git@bitbucket.org:mytmteam/abc.git', :branch => 'debug101'
```

Comment: Why don't you just use an editor to fix up those 13 lines?

Comment: I wish I could do that but this will be automated so editing myself if out of picture

Comment: Editing source code is quite brittle; is there a reason you don't simply use Ruby itself to decide what to enable e.g. based on command-line options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This matches each line from Modules.txt in Main.txt and appends `, :binary => true` to the line. It's fragile but assuming that the input data would be in a similar format to the one given in the question, it will work fine.

```
while IFS="" read -r line; do
    sed -i "/^${line}/s/$/, :binary => true/" Main.txt
done < Module.txt
```

Comment: As described he wanted to extract line from Module.txt and used that as a pattern to match in the 2nd file.

Comment: As mentioned in Question only Main.txt will be modified with the matching entries of modules.txt

Comment: Ah sorry, I misread the question. The regex still matches up with the entries that would be taken from Modules.txt so this would work fine for this particular data. Will edit the answer with a proper fix in some time.

Comment: Reformat to a line per statement so it's more obvious that your solution is better (readable, maintainable) than mine :-)

Comment: Move `do` to next line instead of ;.  IFS='' before read otherwise it strips out the leading spaces and like my answer tag on the ^ to match prefix.  s/Modules.txt/Module.txt/ to match question.  Removed trialing trailing `.  Well done!

Comment: Thanks! Removed the redundant `.*` in the match aswell since we're appending to the end of line anyways so it doesn't matter. I prefer to keep `do` on the same line as `while`.

Answer (score 0):

Transform Module.txt into a suitable regex, then modify Main.txt in-place:

```
match=$(sed '$!s/.*/^&.*\\|/; $s/.*/^&.*/' Module.txt | tr -d '\n')
sed -i "/$match/s/$/, :binary => true/" Main.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's#.*#/&/ba#' modulesFile | sed -f - -e 'b;:a;s/$/, :binary => true/' file
```

Create a sed command file from the `modulesFile` and pipe it through to a second invocation of sed run against `file`

N.B. If a line in `file` does not match the addresses in the `modulesFile` it will not be amended i.e. the `b` command breaks out before the substitution.